# Fresh install of ubuntu 22.04 and 404 not found error even though there are no PPAs causing these errors

Tags: apt, updates, wine, ppa, steam

Well, I'm trying to install steam, wine and lutris on a fresh install of ubuntu 22.04.... but I'm getting several 404 not found errors while trying to install them from terminal command.
I must point out that the 2 only PPAs that I have added are for TeamViewer and KeepassXC, no other PPA has been added, and I have also enabled multiverse and restricted.

I cannot understand why I'm getting these errors... here's a terminal output while trying to install Steam from ubuntu repositories `sudo apt install steam`

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 gcc-12-base i386 12-20220319-1ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:2 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libgcc-s1 i386 12-20220319-1ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:3 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libcrypt1 i386 1:4.4.27-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:4 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libc6 i386 2.35-0ubuntu3
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:5 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libcap2 i386 1:2.44-1build3
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:6 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libgpg-error0 i386 1.43-3
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:7 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libgcrypt20 i386 1.9.4-3ubuntu3
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:8 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 liblz4-1 i386 1.9.3-2build2
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:9 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 liblzma5 i386 5.2.5-2ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:10 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libzstd1 i386 1.4.8+dfsg-3build1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:11 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 libsystemd0 i386 249.11-0ubuntu3.4
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:12 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libdrm2 i386 2.4.110-1ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:13 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libdrm-amdgpu1 i386 2.4.110-1ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:14 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libdrm-nouveau2 i386 2.4.110-1ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:15 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libdrm-radeon1 i386 2.4.110-1ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:16 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 zlib1g i386 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu9
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:17 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libelf1 i386 0.186-1build1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:18 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libexpat1 i386 2.4.7-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:19 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 libglapi-mesa i386 22.0.1-1ubuntu2.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:20 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libatomic1 i386 12-20220319-1ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:21 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libmd0 i386 1.0.4-1build1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:22 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libbsd0 i386 0.11.5-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:23 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libtinfo6 i386 6.3-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:24 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libedit2 i386 3.1-20210910-1build1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:25 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libffi8 i386 3.4.2-4
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:26 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libstdc++6 i386 12-20220319-1ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:27 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libicu70 i386 70.1-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:28 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libllvm13 i386 1:13.0.1-2ubuntu2
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:29 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libsensors5 i386 1:3.6.0-7ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:30 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libvulkan1 i386 1.3.204.1-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:31 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 libgl1-mesa-dri i386 22.0.1-1ubuntu2.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:32 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libglvnd0 i386 1.4.0-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:33 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libxau6 i386 1:1.0.9-1build5
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:34 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libxdmcp6 i386 1:1.1.3-0ubuntu5
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:35 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libxcb1 i386 1.14-3ubuntu3
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:36 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libx11-6 i386 2:1.7.5-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:37 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libx11-xcb1 i386 2:1.7.5-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:38 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libxcb-dri2-0 i386 1.14-3ubuntu3
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:39 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libxcb-dri3-0 i386 1.14-3ubuntu3
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:40 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libxcb-glx0 i386 1.14-3ubuntu3
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:41 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libxcb-present0 i386 1.14-3ubuntu3
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:42 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libxcb-shm0 i386 1.14-3ubuntu3
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:43 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libxcb-sync1 i386 1.14-3ubuntu3
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:44 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libxcb-xfixes0 i386 1.14-3ubuntu3
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:45 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libxext6 i386 2:1.3.4-1build1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:46 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libxfixes3 i386 1:6.0.0-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:47 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libxshmfence1 i386 1.3-1build4
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:48 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libxxf86vm1 i386 1:1.1.4-1build3
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:49 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 libglx-mesa0 i386 22.0.1-1ubuntu2.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:50 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libglx0 i386 1.4.0-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:51 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libgl1 i386 1.4.0-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:52 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 libudev1 i386 249.11-0ubuntu3.4
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:53 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libxi6 i386 2:1.8-1build1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:54 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libxinerama1 i386 2:1.1.4-3
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:55 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse i386 steam i386 1:1.0.0.74-1ubuntu2
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:56 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libblkid1 i386 2.37.2-4ubuntu3
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:57 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libdb5.3 i386 5.3.28+dfsg1-0.8ubuntu3
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:58 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libkrb5support0 i386 1.19.2-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:59 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libk5crypto3 i386 1.19.2-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:60 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libkeyutils1 i386 1.6.1-2ubuntu3
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:61 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libkrb5-3 i386 1.19.2-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:62 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libgssapi-krb5-2 i386 1.19.2-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:63 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libpcre2-8-0 i386 10.39-3build1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:64 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libselinux1 i386 3.3-1build2
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:65 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libmount1 i386 2.37.2-4ubuntu3
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:66 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libtirpc3 i386 1.3.2-2build1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:67 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libnsl2 i386 1.3.0-2build2
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:68 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libuuid1 i386 2.37.2-4ubuntu3
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:69 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 libapparmor1 i386 3.0.4-2ubuntu2.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:70 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libdbus-1-3 i386 1.12.20-2ubuntu4
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:71 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libglib2.0-0 i386 2.72.1-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:72 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libunistring2 i386 1.0-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:73 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libidn2-0 i386 2.3.2-2build1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:74 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libpng16-16 i386 1.6.37-3build5
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:75 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe i386 libva2 i386 2.14.0-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:76 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe i386 libigdgmm12 i386 22.1.2+ds1-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:77 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe i386 intel-media-va-driver i386 22.3.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:78 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libasound2 i386 1.2.6.1-1ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:79 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libsamplerate0 i386 0.2.2-1build1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:80 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libjack-jackd2-0 i386 1.9.20~dfsg-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:81 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libasyncns0 i386 0.8-6build2
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:82 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libogg0 i386 1.3.5-0ubuntu3
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:83 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libflac8 i386 1.3.3-2build2
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:84 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libopus0 i386 1.3.1-0.1build2
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:85 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libvorbis0a i386 1.3.7-1build2
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:86 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libvorbisenc2 i386 1.3.7-1build2
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:87 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libsndfile1 i386 1.0.31-2build1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:88 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libpulse0 i386 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:89 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libasound2-plugins i386 1.2.6-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:90 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libbrotli1 i386 1.0.9-2build6
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:91 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libfreetype6 i386 2.11.1+dfsg-1build1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:92 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libfontconfig1 i386 2.13.1-4.2ubuntu5
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:93 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libpixman-1-0 i386 0.40.0-1build4
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:94 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libxcb-render0 i386 1.14-3ubuntu3
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:95 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libxrender1 i386 1:0.9.10-1build4
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:96 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libcairo2 i386 1.16.0-5ubuntu2
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:97 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libdatrie1 i386 0.2.13-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:98 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libwayland-client0 i386 1.20.0-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:99 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libdecor-0-0 i386 0.1.0-3build1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:100 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libgraphite2-3 i386 1.3.14-1build2
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:101 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libharfbuzz0b i386 2.7.4-1ubuntu3
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:102 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libthai0 i386 0.1.29-1build1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:103 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libpango-1.0-0 i386 1.50.6+ds-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:104 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libpangoft2-1.0-0 i386 1.50.6+ds-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:105 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libpangocairo-1.0-0 i386 1.50.6+ds-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:106 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libwayland-cursor0 i386 1.20.0-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:107 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libdecor-0-plugin-1-cairo i386 0.1.0-3build1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:108 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libpciaccess0 i386 0.16-3
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:109 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libdrm-intel1 i386 2.4.110-1ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:110 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libwayland-server0 i386 1.20.0-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:111 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 libgbm1 i386 22.0.1-1ubuntu2.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:112 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 libegl-mesa0 i386 22.0.1-1ubuntu2.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:113 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libnss-nis i386 3.1-0ubuntu6
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:114 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libnss-nisplus i386 1.3-0ubuntu6
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:115 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libwayland-egl1 i386 1.20.0-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:116 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libxcursor1 i386 1:1.2.0-2build4
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:117 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libxkbcommon0 i386 1.4.0-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:118 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libxrandr2 i386 2:1.5.2-1build1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:119 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libxss1 i386 1:1.2.3-1build2
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:120 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 libsdl2-2.0-0 i386 2.0.20+dfsg-2ubuntu1.22.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:121 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libxcb-randr0 i386 1.14-3ubuntu3
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:122 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe i386 mesa-va-drivers i386 22.0.1-1ubuntu2.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:123 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 mesa-vulkan-drivers i386 22.0.1-1ubuntu2.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:124 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe i386 i965-va-driver i386 2.4.1+dfsg1-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:125 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe i386 va-driver-all i386 2.14.0-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:126 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 libegl1 i386 1.4.0-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-12/gcc-12-base_12-20220319-1ubuntu1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-12/libgcc-s1_12-20220319-1ubuntu1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxcrypt/libcrypt1_4.4.27-1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
```

And all the rest of the "Failed to fetch"...

I get similar errors while trying to install Wine `sudo apt install wine-stable`
Is it because they haven't yet released the versions for 22.04 or is something else wrong?
I must also point out that I have executed the command `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`.
Thanks for any helptime and effort on your part.

Comment: Try the change your "Ubuntu Software" → "Download from" server at the "Settings" of `update-manager`.

Comment: ohh wow!! You were right, my local server didn't have the files... So when I changed to "Main Server" I was able to fetch the files and install. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credits to @FedKad for this answer, he pointed out that I should try to change the server on "Software and Updates", I changed from my local server to the "Main server" and was able to fetch the files.

Thanks a lot @FedKad